# Fast C++ String Output

Tags: c++, c, string, performance, concatenation

I have a program that outputs the data from an FPGA. Since the data changes EXTREMELY fast, I'm trying to increase the speed of the program. Right now I am printing data like this

```
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    printf("data: %d\n",getData(i));
}
```

I found that using one printf greatly increases speed

```
printf("data: %d \n data: %d \n data: %d \n",getData(1),getData(2),getData(3));
```

However, as you can see, its very messy and I can't use a for loop. I tried concatenating the strings first using `sprintf` and then printing everything out at once, but it's just as slow as the first method. Any suggestions?

Edit: 
I'm already printing to a file first, because I realized the console scrolling would be an issue. But its still too slow. I'm debugging a memory controller for an external FPGA, so the closer to the real speed the better.

Comment: any chance to store data and print them afterwards?

Comment: @evilruff I suggested that in my answer, as well.

Comment: Do you have a benchmark on: std::cout << "data: " << getData(i) << '\n'

Comment: can you really read that fast?

Comment: Hopefully getData is an inline

Comment: It's often a good idea to explain why you are doing a thing when asking this kind of question. Do you actually want the data printed numerically or are you writing it to a file for subsequent inspection?

Comment: Normally `stdout` is line-buffered by default. Change it to fully buffered (using `setvbuf()` with `_IOFBF`) or use `fprintf()` with a file stream: this improves the loop (see sehe's answer). The reason your approach with `sprintf()` is slow is that you used it for "concatenating" the strings which probably amounted to something with quadratic complexity and was probably the reason this approach was slow.

Comment: `xxxxprintf` functions are generally slow (quiet big formatting engine), but every tutorial start on printf so is used. Discussion about microseconds "to loop or not to loop" have not sense

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Wow, I can't believe I didn't do this earlier.

```
const int size = 100;
char data[size];
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    *(data + i) = getData(i);
}

for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    printf("data: %d\n",*(data + i));
}
```

As I said, `printf` was the bottleneck, and `sprintf` wasn't much of an improvement either. So I decided to avoid any sort of printing until the very end, and use pointers instead

Answer (score 10):

If you are writing to stdout, you might not be able to influence this all.

Otherwise, set buffering

- setvbuf http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/c/setvbuf
- std::nounitbuf http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/manip/unitbuf
- and un`tie` the input output streams (C++) http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/tie
- `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)` (thanks @Dietmar)

Now, Boost Karma is known to be pretty performant. However, I'd need to know more about your input data.

Meanwhile, try to buffer your writes manually: **[Live on Coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/view?id=b65f7a3bba045ebc87929f7bd966224e-2a3fe95dcf1cc6a0697a1eceaa834f39)**

```
#include <stdio.h>

int getData(int i) { return i; }

int main()
{
    char buf[100*24]; // or some other nice, large enough size
    char* const last = buf+sizeof(buf);
    char* out = buf;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        out += snprintf(out, last-out, "data: %d\n", getData(i));
    }

    *out = '\0';
    printf("%s", buf);
}
```

Comment: Added a simple example on how to buffer all the writes before printing

Comment: Since you mention C++ improvements involving stream, the first port of call should `std::ios_base::sync_with_stdio(false)`. Only the first call affects `printf()`, though.

Comment: @DietmarKühl I knew I was forgetting one :/ Thanks! Yeah, and my answer was two-track (I actually intended to show Boost Karma, but there's little information to go with).

Comment: @sehe how is this any different from what I already did (concatenating all the strings using sprintf and then printing it at the end)?

Comment: @woojoo666 You can keep the for loop! (Quoting your question: _"However, as you can see, its very messy and I can't use a for loop"_)

Comment: sorry, I guess i wasn't clear enough. i already tried concatenating all the strings using sprintf before printing them out, but thanks anyways!

Comment: Oh, good thing I mentioned 4 different potential performance tweaks, and offered to write a Karma sample for benchmarking (given more exact specifications) before I went on to address concatenating into a buffer _using the same for loop_. All of which addressed _specific_ points in the question. I don't think those were misunderstandings. (I hope it helps you or others some time in the future.)

Comment: @sehe was revisiting this question randomly and realized I never responded to your comment. So for future readers: the reason why I didn't choose this approach was because `snprintf` was still too slow. I'm guessing it was the fancy `"data: %d\n", getData(i)` string formatting. So instead, I first saved all the raw data to a buffer, and at the end I formatted and printed it. You can see this in the answer I accepted below

Comment: @woojoo666: it's not the formatting. Now that I've read both answers twice, the problem is the write to the console. Writing to the console is slow. The accepted answer worked because it did all the work without writing to the console in the middle.

Comment: Yup this much was the premise indeed. That is also the exact opening sentence of my answer ;)

Answer (score 3):

How much data?  Store it in RAM until you're done, then print it.  Also, file output may be faster.  Depending on the terminal, your program may be blocking on writes.  You may want to select for write-ability and write directly to STDOUT, instead.

basically you can't do lots of synchronous terminal IO on something where you want consistent, predictable performance.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you format your text to a buffer, then use the `fwrite` function to write the buffer.

Building off of dasblinkenlight's answer,  use `fwrite` instead of `puts`.  The `puts` function is searching for a terminating nul character.  The `fwrite` function writes as-is to the console.

```
char buf[] = "data: 0000000000\r\n";
for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
    // int portion starts at position 6
    itoa(getData(i), &buf[6], 10);

    // The -1 is because we don't want to write the nul character.
    fwrite(buf, 1, sizeof(buf) - 1, stdout);
}
```

You may want to read all the data into a separate raw data buffer, then format the raw data into a "formatted" data buffer and finally blast the entire "formatted" data buffer using one `fwrite` call.

You want to minimize the calls to send data out because there is an overhead involved.  The `fwrite` function has about the same overhead for writing 1 character as it does writing 10,000 characters.  This is where buffering comes in.  Using a 1024 buffer of items would mean you use 1 function call to write 1024 items versus 1024 calls writing one item each.  The latter is 1023 extra function calls.

Comment: `char buf[] = "data: 0000000000\r\n";` if is in auto memory cost copying (by hidden runtime), but if is in static memory IS AN ERROR;

Answer (score -1):

Try printing an `\r` at the end of your string instead of the usual `\n` -- if that works on your system. That way you don't get continuous scrolling.

It depends on your environment if this works. And, of course, you won't be able to read all of the data if it's changing *really* fast.

Have you considered printing only every *n* th entry?